# iOS SMS scheme in HTML hyperlink with body

Tags: html, ios, sms, href

We are trying to create a hyperlink in HTML page which should open predefined SMS - when user taps this link on our page, SMS app should open up with predefined number and body. We were able to successufully set the number, but we are unable to set body of this text message. Is it possible?

The link we are so far trying is :

`<a href="sms:123456789?body=sometext">sms link</a>`

Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No**, it is not possible.

> The sms scheme is used to launch the Messages app. The format for URLs
>   of this type is “sms:”, where  is an optional parameter
>   that specifies the target phone number of the SMS message. This
>   parameter can contain the digits 0 through 9 and the plus (+), hyphen
>   (-), and period (.) characters. **The URL string must not include any
>   message text or other information.**

Reference : [iPhoneURLScheme SMS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH7-SW1)

Comment: thanks a lot, that "solves" the problem ... it is possible to do it in native app thought ...

Answer (score 10):

For iOS 8:

```
<a href="sms:123456789&body=sometext">sms link</a>
```

i customizing while removing the phone number 1234... so user can input the number of their choice in order to share links of my app

Answer (score 7):

At the moment I got these situations working:

works on iOS 8 (have not tested iOS 7):

```
<a href="sms:123456879&body=bodytext">Send sms</a>
```

works on Android 4.x, NOT ON 5.x

```
<a href="sms:123456879?body=bodytext">Send sms</a>
```

I have also tested smsto but that did not matter to make it work on Android 5

Check this fiddle to test:

https://jsfiddle.net/w4vcyjfw/14/

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, it is possible.

A small gift, on ios 5 and 6

`<a href="sms:123456789;body=sometext">sms link</a>`

Comment: Support for this was removed in IOS7 at least tested on IPhone 5, it definitely still works in IOS 5 and 6.

Comment: @DavidC Any guesses as to why this was removed? Security Issues?

Comment: I am guessing marketing politics to promote native app development.

Comment: For iOS8, you may use the format "sms:123456789&body=someText"