# send text code phonegap ios

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-build

I need to add a "share this app via text" button to my app.  I am currently using Phonegap 3.3.  I use this code

```
<a href="sms:;body=http://google.com">share via text</a>
```

This works fine for Android, but on iOS devices it doesn't pass the subject or actual content of the message though.

Answer (score 0):

> No, it is not possible.
>
> The sms scheme is used to launch the Messages app. The format for URLs
>   of this type is “sms:”, where is an optional parameter that specifies
>   the target phone number of the SMS message. This parameter can contain
>   the digits 0 through 9 and the plus (+), hyphen (-), and period (.)
>   characters. The URL string must not include any message text or other
>   information.

Answer was taken from this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165393/ios-sms-scheme-in-html-hyperlink-with-body).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, if you make a phonegap plugin that in turn uses this  [Native API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)  to get the result you are looking for:

Here's a tutorial that helps too:
http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/how-to-send-an-sms-progammatically.html