# I would like to send an SMS message that includes a hyperlink

Tags: php, html, sms

When I do the following, the link comes out as standard text. Is there an esc sequence or something to tell the SMS that this is a link?

```
$email ="xxxx@xxxx.com"
$link = "http://www.google.com";
$phonenumber = "5555555"
$message    =   $email. " wants you to download xxxx, the awesome new app from     xxxx. Tap the link to download ". $link;


$client->account->messages->create(array( 
            'To' => $phonenumber, 
            'From' => "+15555555", 
            'Body' => $Message));
```

Answer (score 3):

No. The SMS format doesn't support any form of markup.

SmartPhones will tend to hyperlink strings of text in SMS that match the pattern of a URL, but that's all you can do (and what you appear to be doing already).

Comment: I saw another can do like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165393/ios-sms-scheme-in-html-hyperlink-with-body

Comment: @KornkritLeelhaphunt — That's about putting a hyperlink **to** an SMS number **in an HTML document** not about putting a link **in an SMS**.

Comment: @KornkritLeelhaphunt — Yes, it works. It just has nothing to do with what the question is asking.

Comment: my mistake to understood this question so sorry

Answer (score -1):

OK, so iOS handles the link just fine in their SMS support. No special coding required. Now to test on Android...